# Oracle use a string inside IN condition

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I have a select statement where I use the IN condition, and inside the IN condition I have a string...how can I ignore the single quotes?

```
Select * from employ where id = 12 and org_id in ({$id})
$id = '12,13'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`in` is used with `collections`, so your input string first should be converted into `collection` (by breaking into rows, based on comma delimiter)

Try something like this

```
Select * from employ where id = 12 and org_id in (
SELECT decode(:input_id,null,  (select  employ.org_id from dual) 
,TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(temp, '[^,]+', 1, level)) )  
    FROM (SELECT  :input_id temp FROM DUAL)
    CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT(temp, '[^,]+')
    )
```

by the way, this `org_id in ()` will return `true` if `:input_id` is `null`.

**Another approach** would be to construct the whole query as a string first and then execute it either with `execute immediate` or through `php`. However this could raise [sql injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) concerns.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you want to process a list.  Unfortunately, SQL doesn't allow a parameter to be a list, so you have to do more work.

One method uses `like` (or a regular expression):

```
Select *
from employ
where id = 12 and
      ',' || org_id || ',' like '%,' || {$id} || ',%';
```

If performance is an issue and you want to use indexes, you may need to investigate other options.  The simplest is to dispense with the parameter and just modify the query string (using dynamic SQL to execute the query).

Comment: The problem was that when you use '12,13' inside IN function you get invalid number....because the IN function reads  12 & 13 as a single number.....

Comment: "Invalid number" means the input is not a valid number. IN is a condition, not a function. The compiler (not IN) reads '12,13' as exactly what it is, a STRING, not a number. THAT raises the 'invalid number' error.