# Oracle 12c - dynamically generate a where clause based on a value in a different table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql, oracle12c

I am trying to write an Oracle 12c SQL statement like this:

```
select * from table1 where col1 in (*dynamicvalue*)
```

I want the dynamic value to be the result of the following SQL:

```
select col2 from table2 where rowid = 1
```

Is this possible? Col2 contains a list of values like this: 'val1','val2','val3'

Thank you

Comment: the result from the second query is not a *list*. you should look at `join`s. there is no need for dynamic sql here.

Comment: Maybe I didn't word it correctly, a single record of Col2 a list of values like this: 'val1','val2','val3'

Comment: possible duplicate with [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39290079/oracle-use-a-string-inside-in-condition/39290316#39290316)

Comment: You should fix your data structure, so lists are not stored in a single column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of dynamic-sql, you can split the string and perform the query. To split the string use `regexp_substr`.

```
select * from table1 
where col1 in (select regexp_substr(col2,'[^,]+', 1, level)  
               from table2
               connect by regexp_substr(col2, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null)
```

Comment: Thank you! I think this is the right path. Is there a way to use dynamic SQL too?

Comment: i don't know a way to do this with dynamic-sql.

Comment: @AAA - what do you mean by "use dynamic SQL too"? I am afraid you don't use the word "dynamic" in its established, technical sense. Are you looking to have variable table or column names? If not, you don't want "dynamic" SQL; instead of using big words, it would be better to explain what you want, in simple, plain-English words.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do this?

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where t1.col1 in (select col2 from table2 where rowid = 1);
```

EDIT:

Storing lists of values in a single column is such a bad idea that I interpreted the question incorrectly.  I took the "list of values" to be the values stored in *different* rows.  Why?  Because that is the right way to store the data.  It is not SQLish to store lists of columns in a delimited list.

That said, we are sometimes stuck with other people's really bad design decisions.  You can use a query such as this, if you are in this situation:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where exists (select 1
              from table2 t2
              where rowid = 1 and
                    ',' || t2.col2 || ',' like '%,' || t1.col1 || ',%'
             );
```

Comment: I believe OP means that `col2` is a string containing `'val1', 'val2', 'val3'` - i.e. he wants the query to execute as `SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE COL1 IN ('val1', 'val2', 'val3')` - or at least that's how I read it. YMMV. :-)

Comment: @BobJarvis . . . That makes so much sense.  I had interpreted that as a single value on each row.